# Nested RecyclerView : onBindViewHolder getting called infinitely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

Let's make this real simple. I've two model classes, `Category` and `Movie`.

```kotlin
data class Category(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val movies: List<Movie>
)

data class Movie(
    val name : String
)
```

Each category has multiple movies. So to render this data, I am using nested `RecyclerView`s. 
[image]

- **The problem**

When I turn the device to landscape mode, the `onBindViewHolder` of `MoviesAdapter` (nested recyclerview's adapter) getting called **infinitely**. (Note, the same code works perfectly fine in portrait mode )

- **What I tried**

I've changed the `layout_width` of nested recyclerview's item to `200dp` from `120dp`, and that's fixed the infinite call in a device, but on a larger screen I had put higher value to fix it.

I know this not an ideal solution, so I tried 'wrap_content` but it didn't work either. (same infinite call issue)

- **Questions**

  1. Why the `onBindViewHolder` getting called infinitely ?
  2. What's the perfect way to fix this issue ?

As I don't want to flood the question feed with the code, I've hosted the [**reproducible version here**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LBZ-tL4ItbBIsnCpJlfAwMHUbVcvfz4i) (code minimized for the sake of readability)

Comment: Is it really infinitely or just until all data is laid out (categories x movies)?

Comment: @Pawel I just noticed that, once I start scrolling, and walked through every data (all categories and all movies), It's getting stopped.

Comment: Looked at your layout files, don't use wrap content height on main recycler view because it messes up recycling behavior. Use 0dp and constraint it to parents bottom.

Comment: Oh my godd...!!! That fixed everything. I didn't know the bottom constraint has this much importance.  You should create an answer to this question. I'll accept it. (y) @Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by setting **bottom constraint** to main `RecyclerView` as [@Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) suggested in the comments.